# How to handle nested XML tags in Go?

Tags: xml, go

I am trying to unmarshal a query response from the protein database (pdb). I have been reading on the XML encoding package of Go, and understand how to handle tags, but I do not know how to handle nested tags. I get as output from code below (cutout);

```
 <PDBdescription> 
 <PDB structureId="4HHB"....
 </PDBdescription>
```

How can I get the info on the structureId? for it seems that it is connected to PDB-tag, which is within the PDBdescription-tag?

```
// pdbRequest
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "encoding/xml"
    //"strings"
)

type PDB struct {
    id    string   `xml:"PDBdescription">"PDB structureId"`
    XMLName xml.Name 
}

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "www.rcsb.org:http")
    p := PDB{id:"NONE"}
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "GET /pdb/rest/describePDB?structureId=4hhb HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
    status := make([]byte, 10000)
    conn.Read(status)
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(status), &p)
    fmt.Println(string(status))
    fmt.Println(p.id)
}
```

I see that my question is very similar to other questions here (putting in link references soon), but the answers given there seems not to be my solution because my tag is a bit different.

Comment: XML aside, why are you using `net.Dial` for http requests?

Comment: It might make it easier to answer this if you make your sample code playground-friendly. Instead of fetching data from a URL, put some example data in a multiline string, and pass that to xml.Unmarshal. Then put the whole thing on play.golang.org and add that link to your question.

Comment: @nemo. I just prefer using net.Dial to have contact with "low level" socket thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need can use the `,attr` modifier when tagging your struct field.  For example:

```
type PDB struct {
    StructureId string `xml:"structureId,attr"`
}

type root struct {
    Pdb PDB `xml:"PDBdescription>PDB"`
}
```

If you decode into a `root` instance, the `structureId` attribute will be decoded into the nested `Pdb.StructureId` field.

Unfortunately you can't combine the chaining syntax with the `,attr` modifier at this point, so you will need a nested struct.

Here is a working example: http://play.golang.org/p/VhUBKKLfk4

Comment: thank you so much, James. I tried a bit of everything with no solution. I will look at it asap.